# How does the Large Address Aware flag work for 32 bit applications on 64-bit computers?

Tags: winapi, memory-management, 32bit-64bit, portable-executable

I've been reading that 32bit Windows applications are limited to 2 GB RAM because the upper 2GB of addressing space is reserved for the Windows OS (and, iirc, VRAM). If you use the /3GB flag on 32-bit WinXp you might get up to 3 GB of RAM available for addressing, but usually you have to tweak with userva values. I've heard that on 64 bit editions of Windows, with a large address aware flag in the PE header and over 4 GB of RAM, it is possible for an application to use all 4 GB of addressing space for its own memory management.

On the other hand, I'm pretty sure that when you call the windows API, you have to call memory locations within the 32-bit address space you're provided. So, exactly how much RAM can a 32-bit large address aware application use for itself in a 64-bit environment, really? And why?

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The virtual address space is extended to 4GB. If you don't use the [Address Windowing Extension API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366527(v=vs.85).aspx), the maximum amount of memory you can access is 4GB. Some of that space will be taken up by the OS for .dlls and other such things, but it will be possible for you to get memory back that uses all 32-bits of a pointer.

Incidentally, if you aren't large address aware, all memory pointers will not be negative when cast to a `INT_PTR`. This is actually a source of more than a few subtle bugs when using the large address aware flag, as pointers are treated signed values.

Comment: Wait a moment, in that case, is it possible to use AWE on a 32-bit Windows Xp OS to properly take advantage of 4 GB of RAM instead of the /3GB silliness?

Comment: +1 If you are planning on running under /LARGEADDRESSAWARE then be warned that various software has bugs with 32 bit pointers >2GB. Even some MS API functions (I'm looking at you GetCursorPos on Vista!) The way to flush out these problems, and work around them if you need to is to use [top down memory allocation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/isv/bb190527(l=en-us)) which is enabled with a registry setting.

Comment: Yes, but you have to explicitly map the physical memory pages to a virtual address space. It's similar to VESA bank switching from the good old DOS era.

Comment: @David, I thought that LargeAddressAware was only (or mainly) a problem for source code that subtracts two pointers (as they can now be further apart than -2GB or +2GB.  Thanks for the reference to GetCursorPos.

Comment: @Patrick I run with top down memory allocation enabled. I've had real problems finding a virus scanner that works under that setting - ended up with MSE after trying about 4 others. Very little code is still around that fails with >2GB pointers, but there are occasional glitches, GetCursorPos is the one that has bitten me. I can replace it with GetCursorInfo, but it's harder in 3rd party code that runs in my process, e.g. HTML help viewer!

Comment: I actually avoid antivirus tools as they slow down my PC and give me a headache with a lot of my programs (AV: "Great scott! This program does DLL injection!" <- Me: "Yes, it's quite useful."). Keep your firewalls in careful order, know what you're running, check for security patches regularly, and you'll be fine imo.